# Is there an easier way to refresh a datasource in VS2022 than deleting it and re-creating it?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, visual-studio-2022

If I change the structure of an object that is used in a datasource of a bindingsource then I need to refresh the datasource so the bindingsource is "aware" of the altered structure.

For example In the control load I have

```
this.bsJobLine.DataSource = typeof(DtoJobLineForOnHold);
```

And I have added a property to my DtoJobLineForOnHold class.

Currently to update a datasource,  I expand the Project->Properties->DataSources and delete the data source.

Then I find my user control ( or form) , wait for the designer to load, right click the binding source, select properties, down click to edit the binding source
[image: binding source dialog]

Select Add new Object Data Source,
filter on my dto name and select it.

What I would like to do is find the DataSource as in step one, right click and refresh it.
Or better still have the build ask me whether to do it automatically.

Is there something I am missing?

[Update]
I am using .net6
When I try View->Other windows-> Data sources I see a message

> This window is not supported for the selected project. For steps to
> enable data binding, please visit

[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: What do you mean by Refreshing data source? Do you mean you have added a Field to the Table in Database, and you want to see it in the corresponding DataTable in a DataSet?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any update.

Comment: Oops it should be there now.

Comment: I Tried it with .NET 4.8 and it works as expected, so when you add a new property and rebuild the project, the data source will be updated.

Comment: There is a DataSource window that you can show by pressing Alt+Shift+D or by going to View->Other Windows->Data Source. There's a refresh button on its toolbar or in context menu of the data sources; you can refresh the data sources. But what I see is, you never need to refresh them, and they always will be updated right after build.

Comment: Also tried with .NET 6, works as expected. The only difference is the Data Source window doesn't work for .NET 6.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question and am now looking at the link... it doesn't seem to offer me steps.